# How to disable Steam broadcasting?

Tags: steam

I enabled Steam broadcasting because it was an annoying option in my way on the in-game Steam menu, although once I enabled it I realised I did not know how to disable it. How do I disable Steam broadcasting?

Comment: Have you tried exiting the game and loading it up again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the client, go in the Settings panel, Broadcast's tab.

[image]

Here's the support [page for broadcasting on steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6730-TOAK-6497#2) :

> The first time a friend requests to watch your game you'll be presented with the broadcast privacy settings. To make a change at any time, access the Steam Client's Settings panel and select the Broadcast tab to view your privacy settings.
>
> Available settings:

```
Broadcast is disabled
Friends can request to watch my games (default)
Friends can watch my games
Anyone can watch my games (public broadcast, can be found in the game hub)
```

Comment: How do I access the settings panel? Sorry I really suck at this stuff.

Comment: @DarkAfterburn See the picture in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused at first but I realized at the bottom means click the box with the downward facing arrow and a drop menu pops out and you can select broadcasting disabled.

Answer (score -2):

However, what isn't mentioned, is that when you restart you PC (and steam restarts) the broadcasting is enabled.

There doesn't seem any way to PERMANENTLY disable broadcasting.